# Get number of entries in properties file apache commons

Tags: java, properties, apache-commons

I'm creating a list of IP address' to ping in which a user can add to the list which is then saved to a properties file in the form of site.name1 = ... site.name2 = ...

Currently I have a for loop with a fixed amount, is there a way to get the number of entries in a properties file so I can set this in the for loop rather than wait for a exception?

```
 PropertiesConfiguration config = configs.properties(new File("IPs.properties"));
            //initially check for how many values there are - set to max increments for loop
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) { //todo fix
                siteName = config.getString("site.name" + i);
                siteAddress = config.getString("site.address" + i);
                SiteList.add(i, siteName);
                IPList.add(i, siteAddress);
            }
```

I've looked through the documentation and other questions but they seem to be unrelated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me based on the documentation you should be able to use PropertiesConfiguration#getLayout#getKeys to get a Set of all keys as a String.

I had to modify the code a bit to use apache-commons-configuration-1.10

```java
        PropertiesConfiguration config = new PropertiesConfiguration("ips.properties");

        PropertiesConfigurationLayout layout = config.getLayout();

        String siteName = null;

        String siteAddress = null;

        for (String key : layout.getKeys()) {
            String value = config.getString(key);

            if (value == null) {
                throw new IllegalStateException(String.format("No value found for key: %s", key));
            }
            if (key.equals("site.name")) {
                siteName = value;
            } else if (key.equals("site.address")) {
                siteAddress = value;
            } else {
                throw new IllegalStateException(String.format("Unsupported key: %s", key));
            }
        }
        System.out.println(String.format("name=%s, address=%s", siteName, siteAddress));
```